# Spring + AngularJs log in architecture

Tags: angularjs, spring, ngroute, angularjs-ng-route

I build a simple app with an **index.jsp** (as a welcome page) and after a form-login submission **directly** to spring controller, i return either index.jsp or homePage.jsp (when user credentials are valid). So angular (routes, components, etc) **loads for the first time at homePage.jsp**.

I chose this implementation due to the fact that i am allowed to use only one ng-view and i wanted to do this only at my homePage from the time that is my main content.I would like some suggestions without using a 3d party routing such as ui-router.

Answer (score 0):

First submit you from from JSP page to Spring Controller

```
<form action = "/checkUser">
        [Your input tags]
</form>
```

In Spring

```
@Controller 
public class Login{
     @RequestMapping("checkUser")
     public String checkUser(@RequestBody Map<String,Object>){
        [Check your user is Valid or not]
     [If valid]
     return "homePage.jsp"
     [else]
     return "Index.jsp"
}
}
```

But rather than this i personally prefer [Spring Security](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/).

Once you got on your homePage you can load all your necessary js file including the annular js files

And load your views using [ng-Route](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute)

```
var app = angular.module('tester', 

['ngRoute']).config(function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
      .when('/tests', {
          templateUrl: 'tests.html',
          controller: 'TestCtrl'
      });
});


app.controller('TestCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){
    $scope.title = "This is a Test Page";
}]);
```

When You click on Tests link

```
<div ng-view></div>
 <a href="#/tests">Test</a>
```

tests.html will directly load in ng-view part

For ng-view [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Pn4rzbFSxcjyfeojJyF1?p=preview)